# Wicket one form with two submit buttons with the same validation

Tags: java, forms, validation, wicket

I use wicket 7.x. I have a form with two submit buttons. The two button do different things on submit event but they have the same field validation. I override the AjaxButton onSubmit in one of them to separate the different behavior but i couldn't pass into the same validation method.

```
button = new AjaxButton("id",this.getRootForm()) {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form){...}
}
button.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);

@Override
protected void onValidate() {...}

@Override
protected void onSubmit() {...}
```

How could i pass through the same validation method with alle the forms?

---

**Edited Answer**

```
this.getRootForm().add(new IFormValidator() {

     @Override
     public void validate(Form<?> form) {
           doValidate(form);
     }
     @Override
     public FormComponent<?>[] getDependentFormComponents() {
         FormComponent<?>[] c = new FormComponent<?>[6];
         c[0] = nome;
         c[1] = email;
         c[2] = cognome;
         c[3] = indirizzo;
         c[4] = telefono;
         c[5] = captcha;
         return c;
      }
});

protected void doValidate(Form<?> form) {...}

button = new AjaxButton("id",this.getRootForm()) {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form){
        doValidate(form);
        if (!form.hasError()) {
            ...
        } else{
            target.add(feedbackPanel);
        }
    }
}
button.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
```

Comment: There is no wicket 1.7, do you mean wicket 7.X by any chance? Also I would recommend not using the `onValidate()` method (not overriding it). Just add Validators to your components and to your Form and any SubmitButton will trigger that validaiton by default unless you exlicitly tell the button not to. See: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/forms2.html#forms2_2

Answer (score 1):

You can add own IFormValidator to form and recall your code.

make your own validate method.

```
void doValidate(Form<?> form) {
   your validation code here for form.
}

this.getRootForm().add(new IFormValidator() {

    void validate(Form<?> form) {
        doValidate(form);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onValidate() {
   doValidate(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure implementing it like this would call the doValidate method twice per submit. IFormValidators will automatically be called in the Forms validate() method, which will then call the overridable onValidate method.

Comment: I resolve using this method. Solution in the edited answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IValidator` or `IFormValidator` and use it in all your `Form`s.

See https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_form_validation_and_feedback_messages

**Update**

```
public class MyValidatingBehavior extends Behavior implements IValidator {


  @Override
  public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
    super.onComponentTag(component, tag);
    if (component.hasErrorMessage()) {
      tag.append("class", "my-error-style", " ");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(final IValidatable<String> validatable) {
    final String candidate = validatable.getValue();
    if (!isValid(candidate)) {
        validatable.error(new ValidationError(this));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing so i can add some code? I mean, now I append Css Class if an error occurs. How can I do so with this validation method?

Comment: @MatteoPezzanera If you want your components to add a css class on case of error you can implement that by writing a `Behaviour` and overriding the `onComponentTag` method. In that method simply check `component.hasErrorMessage()` and modify the tag accodingly